# Chevron - Problems with the responsive behaviour and input field disabled on it

Tags: css, html

I have the following component:

[image]

The problem is that I had to fix the height and it is a big problem when you want to resize the windows. And in the same time I'm not able to use the input fields inserted in that div.

[image: Problems with responsive behaviour]

Here the code:

CSS:

```
#chevron {
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index:-1;     
}

#chevron:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 51%;
  background: #F7F7F7;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
   z-index: -1;
}

#chevron:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: #F7F7F7;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
   z-index: -1;
}​
```

HTML

```
    <div class="row" id="chevron" style="margin-top: 40px; height: 700px;">             
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 40px;">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-5">

             <div class="col-sm-1">
                <div id="circles"> 
                    1 
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-sm-11" style="vertical-align:top;">
                <h2>Maak je pakje klaar</h2>
             </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="" style="padding-top:20px;">
     <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">

        <div class="col-sm-5">
             <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img src="../assets/img/sendingparcel/imgmaak.png" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                 <p> <h3>Verpak je zending</h3><br>
                 Zorg zelf voor een stevige doos
of vind het juiste formaat bij bpost <br><br><a href="#">
Ontdek alle dozen in onze eShop</a><a href="#"><br>Ontdek het aanbod in je postkantoor of PostPunt </a>
                 </p>
            </div> 
             </div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img src="../assets/img/sendingparcel/package.png" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <p><h3>Weeg en meet je pakje 
en vermijd zo een weigering</h3><br>
                         Vanaf een dikte van 3 cm spreken we over een pakje.<br>    Ontdek alle dozen in onze eShop<br>Een pakje mag maximaal 30 kg wegen. </a>
                         </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <br><p class="footnote" style="margin-left:30px;">Controleer ook het formaat. Een pakje moet minimaal 145 mm x 112 mm <br>en mag maximaal 1,5 m lang zijn. De totale oppervlakte is niet meer dan 3 meter: <br>lengte + 2 keer de breedte + 2 keer de hoogte.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div><!-- col-sm-10 -->
</div> <!-- row -->

    </div>
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle.com ? Is impossible to view what happens

Comment: There are too elements to reproduce in a fiddle. So, there are two kind of problems: 1) if you fix the height in the responsive behaviour the columns after will be displayed on the previous element 2) the input fields on the chevron are disabled

Comment: Surely for the first point the problem is about the fixed height, there is a way to set it on the basis of the content ?